# Einstein Email Recommendations Catalog Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am unsure if this question is 'outside the scope' of this forum, but I have nowhere else to turn to. We've gone back and forth with Salesforce support trying to solve this, but they're no help and we're still stumped.

We are trying to implement Einstein Email recommendations under personalization builder in the Marketing Cloud. We installed the dynamic javascript code in our website using google tag manager. When we try to upload the catalog using streaming updates it gives us an error. Support said it was because we had to link a website with a pipe delimited file, however we followed the documentation to the letter and did not find any sort of code for that (I'm in marketing not IT) or explanation as to how to add that. Anybody know how to do this?

I apologize again if this is outside the scope of this forum or if it's too much I'm asking for.

This is my code in the google tag manager for the streaming updates:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      _etmc.push(["updateItem", 
         {
          "item": "ecommerce.detail.id",
          "name": "ecommerce.detail.name",
          "url": "ecommerce.detail.page_url",
          "item_type": "ecommerce.detail.category",
          "availability": "ecommerce.detail.availability",
          "regular_price": "ecommerce.detail.price",
          "image_url": "ecommerce.detail.image"
         }
      ]);
</script>
```

[Here](https://www.gaveteiro.com.br/macacao-de-protecao-covertech-100-g-volk/pg/LyB62W) is the link to a product in our website where you can see the code installed.

Below are the errors that I'm getting in the console and the page source where you can see how these codes were installed:

[image: Product Console]

[image: Page Source]

Here are the docs I followed:

[Stream Catalog Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_streaming_updates.htm&type=5)

[Implementation Doc in MC](https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Email%20Recommendations/ftux/documentations/web)

[Personalization Builder Catalog Definitions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_catalog_field_definition.htm&type=5)

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Payload from site:

```
    var dataLayer = [{
  "site": {
    "domain": "gaveteiro.com.br",
    "name": "Gaveteiro",
    "country": "BR",
    "application": "desktop"
  },
  "page": {
    "template": "Product"
  },
  "session": {
    "isLogged": false,
    "user": {
      "id": "0",
      "salesforceID": "0",
      "accountId": "0",
      "accountSalesforceID": "0"
    }
  },
  "ecommerce": {
    "detail": {
      "id": "0058000135",
      "name": "Macacao de Protecao Covertech 100 G - Volk",
      "price": "0.00",
      "original_price": "12.21",
      "variant": "unica",
      "brand": "VOLK",
      "category": "Vestimenta Descartável",
      "status": "Sob Encomenda",
      "status_id": "2",
      "image": "https://res-1.cloudinary.com/gaveteiro/image/upload/v1563216875/jxlbg6qqprxbh8hxhs5r.jpg",
      "page_url": "https://www.gaveteiro.com.br/macacao-de-protecao-covertech-100-g-volk/pg/LyB62W",
      "availability": "http://schema.org/OutOfStock"
    }
  },
  "remarketing": {
    "ecomm_pagetype": "product",
    "ecomm_prodid": "LyB62W",
    "ecomm_category": "Vestimenta Descartável",
    "ecomm_totalvalue": "12.21"
  },
  "event": "eventRemarketingDinamico"
}];
```

I believe this is it

UPDATE 2:

```
_etmc.push(["updateItem",{item_type:"ecommerce.category",item:"ecommerce.detail.id",name:"ecommerce.name",url:"Page URL",available:"ecommerce.status",sale_price:"ecommerce.id.price"}]);
```

This is what I could find, if this is not what you are looking for, I will talk to my IT dept tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: can you provide the payload you are passing? you can can get this from dev console in your browser

Comment: @EazyE is that what you needed?

Comment: I was looking for something more like https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/c2/xxxxxx/update_item?payload=[{"item_type":"product","item":"SU101Item1","name":"Streaming Update Test 101","url":"http:\\www.google3.com","unique_id":"SU101Item1","available":"N","ImageLink":"http://google.com"}]

Comment: also availability should not be a URL it should be Y/N

Comment: if i go to this url https://www.gaveteiro.com.br/macacao-de-protecao-covertech-100-g-volk/pg/LyB62W I don't see a streaming update call being made

Comment: this url provided is still not making the call to SFMC to do a streaming update. You can see this by opening dev console in your browser and filter by igo and visit your url. Until the call is made nothing is going to happen. Your web developer should look at their implementation of the collect code. If I go to the console tab i see the following errors "ReferenceError: _etmc is not defined"

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is that the collect script is not getting loaded by the time you are making your `_etmc.push()` calls. You have the below code to add in the collect script as async, and then are immediately after making your `_etmc.push()` calls in a sync script block. I would suggest removing the async load from the below script, which *should* ensure it is loaded by the time you attempt to utilize it.

```
(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
a.type="text/javascript";
a.async="true";
a.src="https://XXXXXXX.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js";
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
b.parentNode.(a,b);return a})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code and it works:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXXXX.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXXXXX"]);
 _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      _etmc.push(["updateItem", 
         {
          "item": "123456789",
          "name": "Gloves",
          "url": "https://ntoretail.com/shop/mens/accessories/1600100",
          "item_type": "product",
          "availability": "y",
          "regular_price": "5.00",
          "imagelink": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nto-products/products1110/1600100.jpg"
         }
      ]);
</script>
<body>
 BODY


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Eazye, I am new to personalization builder and can't find an answer to a question that why does marketing cloud needs streaming updates to the catalog twice in a day when the images are static and uploaded/ changed one in a while.